# What is the symbol for an "Answer", if so why we're not using that?

Tags: american-english, question-marks

I know the symbol of question is '?', we use that to ask a question verbally.

But when giving the answer is there any symbol to denote that and if so why we are not using any symbol to mention the same?

Comment: The distinction that must be made is between question and statement.  We can tell from context when a statement is in reply to a preceding question.   The question mark is not a necessity but a convenience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no **answer mark** *per se* in the way there is a **question mark**
Questions usually ask one of the following

> **who
>
>   what
>
>   where
>
>   when
>
>   how
>
>   why**

and are ended with a "**?**"

**Answers** are usually statements of fact and end in either

> "**.**"(period)
>   "**!**"(exclamation mark)

sometimes **a question may be answered with a question** which ends with a "**?**" and this can frustrate the questioner.

**Answers** can start with the word **because**

> Q: **Why** did the chicken cross the road
>   A: **Because** he wanted to get to the other side

You might think of **because** as an **answer marker**, however **not all answers use** "**because**".

Comment: Glad to help. If you think the answer is the one you are looking for, please click the "tick" mark.

Comment: "Because" is only used to reply to "why" questions. If I asked, "Who owns that bicycle?" I'd expect you to respond with the name of a person, not any sort of statement beginning "because". Etc. I don't know of any word that would indicate an answer in general.